# Ignore typescript errors when running assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, webpacker

I have a build server for my production environment that is essentially running:

```
yarn install --prod
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

Now, because my types (eg, `@types/jquery`) are stored as `devDependencies`, they don't get installed via `yarn install --prod`... but without them, the `precompile` fails:

```
ERROR in /path/to/my/file.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /path/to/my/file.ts(129,9)
  TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
```

Is there a way to tell `assets:precompile` to ignore Typescript errors?

OR, am I going about this the entirely wrong way? I'd prefer to not install the `devDependencies` on my build server...

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your situation, I would just install the `devDependencies`.  Compiling TypeScript code is, after all, a development operation.  What is your concern?  Just space usage and running time for the installation?

That said, given that it looks like [webpacker uses ts-loader](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/227661b546701e107213aa9b6f83451bc89cf7d5/lib/install/loaders/typescript.js), another approach you can try is to enable ts-loader's [`transpileOnly` option](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#transpileonly-boolean-defaultfalse) to skip type checking and thereby avoid the errors.  See [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#options) for an example of how to enable `transpileOnly` in your `config/webpack/loaders/typescript.js` file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out `transpileOnly`. My main concern is install time, as we have a good number of `devDependencies` (mostly around unit & E2E testing). I guess, worst case, I could just move the `@types` stuff into `dependencies`...